# Why this JAVA code connot resolve constructor?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to make Calendar Selection box using Swing as University Project.

I don't know what to do when there is an "`Cannot resolve Constructor 'JComboBox(int[])'`" error in the "`public JComboBox YearComboBox=new JComboBox(years);`" part while writing code that initialize items by inserting an array into JComboBox.

this is my code. (Made shorter than existing code.)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class IDfind {
    private int years[]=setYear();
    public JComboBox YearComboBox=new JComboBox(years);

    public int[] setYear() {
        int nowYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int[] year = new int[nowYear];
        for (int i = 0; i <= nowYear - 1900; i++) {
            year[i] = 1900 + i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return year;
    }
```

Comment: Works with boxed types - change your `int`s to `Integer`s.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you are attempting to use the `JComboBox​(E[] items)` constructor for `JComboBox<E>`. However, as `int` is not a reference type, `E` cannot be `int` and to `E[]` cannot be `int[]`.

You need to be using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`. Switching from raw types to generics, you should also use `JComboBox<Integer>`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class IDfind {
    private Integer[] years = setYear();
    private JComboBox<Integer> yearsCombo = new JComboBox<>(years);

    private Integer[] setYear() {
        int nowYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Integer[] year = new Integer[nowYear];
        for (int i = 0; i <= nowYear - 1900; i++) {
            year[i] = 1900 + i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return year;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because there is no constructor for JComboBox which supports int[] as argument.
check available constructors [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(javax.swing.ComboBoxModel))

for e.g. using Vector

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    private Vector years = setYear();
    public JComboBox YearComboBox = new JComboBox(years);

    public Vector setYear() {
        int nowYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Vector year = new Vector(nowYear);
        for (int i = 0; i <= nowYear - 1900; i++) {
            year.add(1900 + i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    return year;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Helping me! Bug was gone! But... I see nothing on JComboBox

Comment: check examples given in https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcombobox-basic-tutorial-and-examples. That might help.

Comment: my IDE(IntelliJ) shows this warning : ① YearComboBox is Overwritten by Generated code. ② Unchecked call to JComboBox(Vector<E>) as member a of raw type 'javax.swing.JComboBox'